# Running Java app from IntelliJ returns different response format

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, jersey, dropwizard

I am trying to call an API in my Dropwizard application, the API returns the following class

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Error")
public class ErrorResponse {

    @NonNull
    @XmlAttribute(name = "msg")
    private String msg;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "display")
    protected String display;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "action")
    private String action;

    @NotNull
    @XmlAttribute(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "code")
    private String code;

}
```

```
return javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(status).entity(ErrorResponse).header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_XML).build();
```

when I ran the application from IntelliJ, I got this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error msg="some message" display="true" action="RETRY" type="FATAL" code="error"/>
```

when I ran it using the jar, I got this:

```
  <ErrorResponse>
        <msg>some message</msg>
        <display>true</display>
        <action>RETRY</action>
        <type>FATAL</type>
        <code>error</code>
    </ErrorResponse>
```

I am using dropwizard 2.0.24

Comment: You are probably missing some depedencies in the jar, looks like the Intellij one is the correct one.

Comment: I am running mvn clean install to build the jar, so it should take the same dependencies that I have in the pom, I m trying to clean .m2 and then to rerun from intellij to see if I still get the same

Comment: Can you post your pom with your dependencies and plugins.

Comment: @GawadAzzam I'm thinking more on plain jar vs https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ . So, your jar is not including the dependency that handles those `XmlAttribute` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't package your jar plain, use the maven-shade-plugin, that will include the dependencies in the jar, or, add these dependencies to your Classpath.

Answer (score 0):

1. after deleting .m2 I got same response from IntelliJ and from the Jar.
2. for some reason Dropwizard 2.0.24 was ignoring my JAXB annotations, I fixed it by changing the version to 2.0.0.

thanks for your comments, much appreciated